# How to inject shared service from compiler pass in Symfony

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I am attempting to inject a token storage service via a compiler pass designed to replace one of the services in the FOSRestBundle:

```
<?php

namespace App\Compiler;

use App\Event\Listener\RestParamConverter;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class RestParamConverterOverride implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * You can modify the container here before it is dumped to PHP code.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('fos_rest.converter.request_body');
        $definition->setClass(RestParamConverter::class);
        $definition->addArgument($container->getDefinition('security.token_storage'));
    }
}
```

For some reason, even though the security system is correctly setting the token in the `TokenStorage`, in my custom service when I access the `TokenStorage`, `$tokenStorage->getToken()` seems to return `null`. I have debugged the code and for sure the authentication is running before I try and retrieve the value.

I have tested with other services and I am seeing the behaviour that whatever I am injecting with `$definition->addArgument($container->getDefinition(SERVICE_HERE));`. It's very strange but in compiler passes it seems to create a new instance of that service rather than use the shared service.

In other parts, service injection is working correctly - just not in these compiler passes. Can anyone shed some light on why this might be?

Comment: You can look at the generated container under the cache directory to see what is going on.  That will at least confirm (or perhaps deny) your suspicion about shared services.

Comment: @Cerad: Yeah, it seems it's being `new`ed rather than using the shared service.

Comment: I have not done much with passes and dynamically modifying service definitions.  But as a shot in the dark have you tried ->addArgument(new Reference('service_name'))

Comment: @Cerad: Fantastic, it worked. Thanks so much! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs show how to inject a reference to an existing service as opposed to creating a new instance of the service: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html#basic-usage

Specifically, use:

```
$definition->addArgument(new Reference('service_name'))
```